# How to select rows in pandas df where value appears also in filtered columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have pandas df which looks similar to this:

```
    0   1   2   3   4
0   r1  v1  v1  v2  v3
1   r2  x   -   x   -
2   r3  x   x   -   x
3   r4  -   -   x   -
```

and I want to get only rows where value 'x' is in column where 'v1' sits - column 0 and 1. So I would get this:

```
    0   1   2   3   4
0   r2  x   -   x   -
1   r3  x   x   -   x
```

how can I do that? I can't merge column 1 with 2 because it has other dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there will be two steps

```
out = df[df.loc[:,df.eq('v1').any()].eq('x').any(1)]
Out[13]: 
    0  1  2  3  4
1  r2  x  -  x  -
2  r3  x  x  -  x
```